# How to add groups in connecting lines connecting dots in boxplots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, boxplot

I made the following dataset:

```r
before <- c(100, 120, 140, 130, 120, 100, 100)  
after <- c(140, 100, 160, 120, 90, 70, 70)  
pain_group <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)  
d <- data.frame(before=before, after=after, pain_group=pain_group)

d$id <- 1:nrow(d)
d <- tidyr::gather(d, Measurement, quantity, -id)
```

I have plotted the data in boxplots with seperate dots and connecting lines:

```r
ggplot(d2, aes(Measurement, quantity_cluster2)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +  
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(group = id), color = 'grey') +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c('before', 'after'))
```

[image]

However I want the `pain_group` seperated with different color lines (and dots). How can I make this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you make this reproducible so that the code can run as-is? (for instance, you reference d2 and a variable called quantity_cluster2)

Comment: Put `color = factor(pain_group)` in your `aes()`. Delete the `color = 'grey'` from your `geom_line` layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude `pain_group` from your `gather` so it is still a column in the long-form data, then add `color = factor(pain_group)` to `aes()`:

```
d2 <- tidyr::gather(d, Measurement, quantity, -id, -pain_group)

ggplot(d2, aes(Measurement, quantity)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +  
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(pain_group))) +
  geom_line(aes(group = id, color = factor(pain_group))) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c('before', 'after'))
```

[image]

You can customize the legend title with `labs()`, or the legend title, labels, and colors with `scale_color_continuous()`.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but a suggestion for a (probably) more compelling visualisation. You're dealing with paired data, so bring it into two dimensions. A scatter plot is perfect for that purpose. Your data is already in the right shape, and you can add a line of equality to make the comparison easier.

```r
library(ggplot2)
before <- c(100, 120, 140, 130, 120, 100, 100)  
after <- c(140, 100, 160, 120, 90, 70, 70)  
pain_group <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)  
d <- data.frame(before=before, after=after, pain_group=pain_group)

lims <- range(c(before, after))

ggplot(d) +
  geom_point(aes(before, after, color = as.character(pain_group))) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = lims, ylim = lims)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>